# How to set transparent background in Bitmap from BitmapImage?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have that function to convert BitmapImage to Bitmap:

```
private Bitmap BitmapImage2Bitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using(MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        enc.Save(outStream);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(outStream);

        return new Bitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

My images have black background (as .PNG they've transparent background).

How can I make them always have a transparent background?

Comment: [Bitmaps do not natively support transparency](https://superuser.com/a/180960/961093)

Comment: @Mind: He is not talking about the BMP format but about the Bitmap class in GDI+ which supports eg ARGB including transparency.

Comment: @Filip: Where do you see that black background?

Answer (score 0):

If your display technology is WinForms, the answer is: You can not really. WinForms is a few decades to old to support proper transparency on the Display side.

Windows Forms is pretty good at feining Transparency, but not that good: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window

Comment: I use WPF, but OpenFileDialog supports only Bitmap.

Comment: @FilipSzymański You are the one setting the file extension filters of the OpenFile dialog. Also it does not mater, if as you never write the file to the disk.

Comment: I see no indication he is talking about Winforms display but about the Bitmaps class which can support transparency just fine.

Comment: @TaW That is why my text started with a big "If". It is a common issue with WindowsForms that many people stumble over.

Comment: Only if one tries to display it in overlapping controls.

Comment: @TaW Wich is about the most common use of Transparent Images in WinForms, isn't it?

Comment: Not really. They work fine in nested controls - And OP wrote he is on WPF and just needs to create a GDI+ Bitmap; he didn't tell us why, so far..

Comment: @TaW He told us he is on WPF in a comment *under this post*. So unless you expected my to be psychic, there was no way for me to know until after I wrote it.